# page pagination jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-plugins, pagination, jquery-pagination

I have tried a jquery to do the page pagination.  The example is showing the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quickpager.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

$(document).ready(function() {


    $("ul.paging").quickPager();


    $("ul.paging2").quickPager({pagerLocation:"both"});
});

/* ]]> */
</script>
<body>
    <h1>SimplePager demo page</h1>
    <p><a href="http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/14/jquery-youtube-playlist-plugin---youtubeplaylist">back to blog post</a></p>
            <code>
            <pre>
    $("ul.paging").quickPager();
            </pre>
        </code>


<ul class="paging">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
</ul>
```

It is diaplaying each 10records in a page :# refrence:`http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/20/simplepager---jquery-paging-plugin--`updated

I used the same, but tried to retrieve the values from the db instead of hard coding, but the pagination is not there, only the 20 records retrieved without the pagination. Can I do this type of code?

```
<% 
while(rs.next()){

%>  
<ul class="paging">
    <li><%=rs.getString("customer_name")%></li>
</ul>

<%

}

rs.close();

%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like this....

```
<ul class="paging">
<% 
    while(rs.next()){    
%>
        <li><%=rs.getString("customer_name")%></li>
<%    
    }    
    rs.close();    
%>    
</ul>
```